# How to write link tag only when `price` is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have code like this in a `ProductDecorator`.

```
 link = if price.present?
           h.link_to self do
             h.number_to_currency(price, precision: 0)
           end
        end
 link ||= '-'
```

If there is no link I could write:

```
price.present? ? h.number_to_currency(price, precision: 0) : '-'
```

The code with link tag seems bit redundant. Is there better way to write the code with link tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `link_to_if`?

I think it'd go something like:

```
link = h.link_to_if(price.present?, h.number_to_currency(price, precision: 0), self) do 
  "-"
end
```

And you could clean it up further if your decorator had a price helper method.

```
def display_price
  h.number_to_currency(price, precision: 0)
end

def link_to_price # or whatever you've called that method
   link_to_if(price.present?, display_price, self) do
     "-"
   end
end
```

Check out [ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelpers docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_if) for more details.